# How do I instigate a re-try for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Beginner here, I'm creating an incredibly simple "Login" style program, currently I have used if statements to see if what the user has entered has matched what I have already declared, if they get it right they get a "Logged in" message, if not then the program terminates.

However, I would like it so the user has a maximum of 3 attempts to get the credentials correct before terminating. How would I go about doing this?

```
List<String> usernames = accessClass.setUsernames();
    List<String> passwords = accessClass.setPasswords();

    System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");

    user1 = wordScan.next();


    if(usernames.contains(user1)){

        System.out.print("Now enter your password: ");

        pass1=wordScan.next();

        if(passwords.contains(pass1)){

            System.out.println("Logged in.");
            System.out.println("Your username is "+user1);

            random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            numGen = random.nextInt(899999)+100000;

            System.out.println("Your access code is: "+numGen);
        }
    }else{

        System.out.println("Invalid Username... Terminating.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    wordScan.close();

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You would use a loop before your first if, which loops 3 times. If the password is correct, your would either break out of the loop, or a smoother and more clean way, set a variable to a specific value which your loop would also check.

Comment: A little offtopic, as I see, you have a bunch of password for a bunch of users, you don't check that user1 have the password1, you check that a string is inside your passwords ¿?

Comment: No, I've not bothered with that yet, can't seem to get my head around the logic, but I'll work on that eventually.

Yes ok I'll have a quick go myself thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use a loop like this:

```
    List<String> usernames = accessClass.setUsernames();
    List<String> passwords = accessClass.setPasswords();

    while(attempts > 0 && !loggedIn) {

        System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");

        user1 = wordScan.next();
        int attempts = 3;
        boolean loggedIn = false;

        attempts = attempts -1;
        if(usernames.contains(user1)){

            System.out.print("Now enter your password: ");

            pass1=wordScan.next();

            if(passwords.contains(pass1)){

                System.out.println("Logged in.");
                System.out.println("Your username is "+user1);
                loggedIn = true;
                random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
                numGen = random.nextInt(899999)+100000;

                System.out.println("Your access code is: "+numGen);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!loggedIn) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username or password... Terminating.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    wordScan.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have used this but you need to move the while loop above where I have called username scanner. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna loop 3 times at most, something like this would do the trick :

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
 ... your code
 // when username + password match : use break; at the end in order not to do the remaining loops
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a `for` or `while` loop should be enough, also, if your array of users and passwords are linked (user1 has pass1, user2 has pass2 and so) you could get the index inside your list with `indexOf` and compare both:

```
if(usernames.contains(user1)){
    System.out.print("Now enter your password: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pass1 = wordScan.next();
        if(passwords.contains(pass1) 
                && usernames.indexOf(user1) == passwords.indexOf(pass1)){
            // correct
            break;
        } else if (i == 2){
            // incorrect and end of try
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    List<String> usernames = accessClass.setUsernames();
    List<String> passwords = accessClass.setPasswords();
    System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
    user1 = wordScan.next();

    int i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        if(usernames.contains(user1)){

        System.out.print("Now enter your password: ");

        pass1=wordScan.next();

        if(passwords.contains(pass1)){

            System.out.println("Logged in.");
            System.out.println("Your username is "+user1);

            random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            numGen = random.nextInt(899999)+100000;

            System.out.println("Your access code is: "+numGen);
            break;
            }
        }else{

            if(i==2) {
             System.out.println("Invalid Username... Terminating.");
             System.exit(0);
             }

             else {
             System.out.println("Invalid Username... Try Again.");
             i++;
             }  
        }
    }
    wordScan.close();
}
```